# Using sed to delete a string between parentheses

Tags: bash, sed

I'm having trouble figuring how to delete a string in between parentheses only when it is in parentheses. For example, I want to delete the string "(Laughter)", but only when it's in parenthesis and not just make it a case sensitive deletion since a sentence within that string starts with Laughter.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I've tried everything I can think of. I just tried MightyPork's answer and that didn't work. The only thing that I haven't tried that I can think of is searching for all strings in parens with grep then deleting them with sed or something. I don't know I'm at a complete loss.

Comment: your question is very unclear, but my commands work.

Comment: Specifically: there is a sentence that reads "word word (Laughter) words word words. Laughter words word." how do I delete the "(Laughter)" and not the other "Laughter" not in parentheses that begins the second sentence? Because I just get "word word Laughter words word words. Laughter words word." from it.

Comment: That works perfectly fine: http://jpeg.cz/images/2015/01/08/480J3.png

Comment: Indeed @MightyPork answer does work. You must be leaving something out in your question, or you're not implementing it correctly.

Comment: @TeddyT it might also help to provide an excerpt of the file you wish to change.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but the following will remove text between parentheses:

```
sed "s/[(][^)]*[)]/()/g" myfile
```

(or as Llama pointed out in comments, just:)

```
sed "s/([^)]*)/()/g" myfile
```

It matches a literal open paren `[(]` followed by any number of non-`)` characters `[^)]*` followed by a literal close paren `[)]`.

Example:

```
$ echo "Blah blah (potato) moo (cow is a pretty bird)(hello)" | sed "s/[(][^)]*[)]/()/g"
Blah blah () moo ()()
```

Use `//` instead of `/()/` there if you don't want the empty parens in the output.

Comment: In sed, you don't *need* the parens in character classes (although it's probably not a bad habit to play it safe).  The following works fine: `sed "s/([^)]*)/()/g"`

Comment: That's because by default (GNU) sed uses "basic" regular expressions, where grouping is done with `\(` and `\)`, not `(` and `)`. see https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Regular-expression-syntaxes.html

Comment: Don't use `cat file | sed`, use `sed '...' file`

Comment: Works too, yeah. Not much of a difference of you just wanna check if it works, no?

Comment: I think @TomFenech is referring to [`The Useless Use of Cat`](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html#cat).  There are some edge cases where using `cat` may lead to unexpected results.  Here's a [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11710552/477563) on the topic.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an `awk` solution because, why not?

```
awk '{gsub("[(][^)]*[)]","")}1' file
```

OR

```
awk -F '[(][^)]*[)]' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i+=1)printf("%s",$i);printf("\n")}' file
```

Remember that in order to escape parentheses use must enclose them in `[]` brackets.

By using `[^)]*`, as @MightyPork did in his answer, which indicates any number of characters that are not parentheses, will reduce the greed of the match. In contrast, using `.*` instead, would result in a greedy match.